# spark structured stream read to hdfs files fails if data is read immediately

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I'd like to load a Hive table (`target_table`) as a DataFrame after writing a new batch out to HDFS (`target_table_dir`) using Spark Structured Streaming as follows:

```
df.writeStream
  .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds')
  .foreachBatch(lambda df, partition_id:
    df.write
      .option("path", target_table_dir)
      .format("parquet")
      .mode("append")
      .saveAsTable(target_table))
  .start()
```

When we immediately read same data back from the Hive table we get a "partition not found exception". If we read with some delay, we have data correct.

It seems that Spark is still writing data to HDFS while execution has stopped and Hive Metastore is updated but data is still being written out to HDFS.

How to know when the writing of data to the Hive table (into the HDFS) is complete?

Note:
we have found that if we use processAllAvailable() after writing out,subsequent read works fine.but processAllAvailable() will block execution forever if we are dealing with continuous streams

Comment: How do you do _"when we immediately try to read same data back from hive table.we are getting partition not found exception."_? How do you know when a table is appended (after a 5-sec trigger is executed)?

Comment: we are not able to identify when table is appended.As part of workflow ,we are trying to read back data as next step and getting error.We need way to identify that table append is finished

Comment: @JacekLaskowski ..we have found that if we use processAllAvailable() after writing out.subsequent read works fine..but processAllAvailable() will block execution forever if we are dealing with continuous streams.

Comment: may be using s3a committer should have fix it